# HeaderStringFormat issue when using Curly Brace next to the beginning quote

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, groupbox

I have the following XAML.  The idea is to append the text " For Report" after a string that is coming from a bound XML file.

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding XMLData.Element[HeadingText].Value}" 
          HeaderStringFormat="For Report">
```

When I add {0} to the beginning of the HeadingStringFormat String like so, the application ignores the HeaderStringFormat and simply puts up the databound value.

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding XMLData.Element[HeadingText].Value}" 
          HeaderStringFormat="{0} For Report">
```

However, when I add a single space (or any other character for that matter) after the quote, but prior to the left {, the application works fine.

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding XMLData.Element[HeadingText].Value}" 
          HeaderStringFormat=" {0} For Report" >
```

In the first example, the editor seems to think that the string (between the quotes) isn't a string anymore, but if I put in that space, it's happy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try prefixing your format string with `{}`. This should work:

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding XMLData.Element[HeadingText].Value}" 
          HeaderStringFormat="{}{0} For Report">
```

For further information, see [MSDN: {} Escape Sequence / Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help, sorry about how long it took to get back to the answer.